# Eclipse - Font changed after updating to Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, fonts

I recently came back to Eclipse after using IntelliJ, and I upgraded to Windows 10.

I've noticed that my font is now different, it is now Courier New (10) (isn't this what Eclipse always used?). It's much more spaced out and I can't handle it.

Both images are using Eclipse Luna.

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kOBr.png

Now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqEB7.png

Edit: I even re-installed Eclipse and didn't notice a difference (including the .eclipse folder)

Answer (score 1):

Solved - Consolas is the font name.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4091364/windows-10-fix-blurry-apps

just enable the option and re-launch eclipse